# Api para organização de arquivos semelhante a estrutura de árvore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algoritmo

Estou desenvolvendo um módulo de reunião, que contém gerenciamento de pautas, as pautas são organizadas da seguinte forma:

```
1. pauta c
    1.1.pauta x
2. pauta v
    2.1. pauta b
      2.1.1. pauta y
```

cada pauta desta é um registro no banco de dados. Tentei de diversas formas, com Jquery, Javascript com arrays, Datatables, porém não obtive sucesso. Nesse módulo preciso implementar a opção de alterar e excluir pautas. Por exemplo, tem que ser possível o usuário selecionar (clicar) uma pauta e clicar em outro botão para transforma-lá em sub-tópico ou deixa-lá apenas como tópico. Ao modelar o sistema, foi utilizado o Agreedo como modelo. Até onde eu entendo essa estrutura é de árvore. Porém estou a procura de algo mais simples.

[image: Agreedo exemplo]

A pergunta é, gostaria de saber se existe uma Api .js que me auxilie nesse desenvolvimento. De preferência uma que abstraia essa parte de árvore. Se caso não tenha, gostaria de uma ideia com a lógica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez eu precisei fazer algo parecido com o que vc esta precisando.
No meu caso eu precisava fazer uma arvore de uma URA para PABX e em cada item da arvore eu precisava disparar um evento onClick.
Eu usei o JSTree, achei ele bem básico e facil de manipular.
 Segue o link:
https://www.jstree.com/
Apenas lembrando, o JSTree não cria eventos, etc (pelo menos eu não criei por ele), essa parte eu tive que fazer na mão. O JSTree vai apenas pegar os dados e mostrar como formato de arvore.
Segue um exemplo de como ficou a minha arvore de dados:
[image: Exemplo de arvore]

Comment: Não era bem isso que eu espera. Mas parece que com essa estrutura da pra fazer.. Vou tentar fazer com ela, pra ver no que vai dar. Depois coloco aqui os resultados